# В чем ошибка в простой программе MASM

Tags: ассемблер, masm32, masm

У меня есть код на ассемблере masm:

```
include console.inc
 
.data
        var1 dq 179
        var2 dq 100
        var3 dq 0
.code
Start:  
        mov var3, var2
        add var3, var1
        outint var3
        exit
        end Start
```

Как надеюсь я, он должен вывести 279, но оно выдает ошибку при сборке:

```
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.14.8444
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1981-1997.  All rights reserved.

 Assembling: hello.asm
hello.asm(9) : error A2070: invalid instruction operands
hello.asm(10) : error A2070: invalid instruction operands
```

Я не понимаю в чем проблема и не могу найти решения в интернете. Я изучаю пока по вот этому сайту: [warmland.ru/cs/masm/](https://https:%5C%5Cwarmland.ru/cs/masm/)

Подскажите пожалуйста, я новичок в assemblere

Comment: ответьте пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечаю.

```
    mov var3, var2
    add var3, var1
```

Одним из базовых правил, которые излагаются на первых страницах любого толкового учебника по ассемблеру для x86/amd64, является следующее: ***в инструкциях с двумя операндами оба операнда не могут быть ячейками памяти!*** Возможны комбинации: память-регистр, память-число, регистр-память, регистр-регистр. Комбинация память-память *запрещена*! Об этом вам транслятор и сообщил.

По-этому, для вычисления выражения `var3 = var2 + var1`, вам надо использовать буферный(ные) регистр(ы).

Для x86 (32-битный ассемблер):

```
;записываем var2 в пару EDX:EAX (у нас же 64-битные вычисления)
mov eax, dword ptr var2
mov edx, dword ptr var2[4]

;складываем с var1
add eax, dword ptr var1
adc edx, dword ptr var1[4]

;записываем результат в var3
mov dword ptr var3, eax
mov dword ptr var3[4], edx
```

Для amd64 (хотя вряд ли это ваш случай):

```
mov rax, var2
add rax, var1
mov var3, rax
```

Ну и да, выводить в консоль надо также 64-битный результат.

Comment: Спасибо большое,

Comment: это помогло, я понял как делать

Comment: @FotonPC дерзайте)